# How to delete Package Dependency Xcode 11

Tags: xcode, dependencies, package

I want to archive my app to upload it to App Store but there is a strange bug. During the archive buildtime I get an error (second picture) related to dependency that are now shown in Swift Packages (first picture), so I can't delete it to get rid of it.

I tried clicking on the left menu on DynamicColor and select "delete" but it doesn't work, the dependency is still there.

Please help me to delete DynamicColor dependency.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, DynamicColor dependency is required by ColorPicker dependency, so I can't delete only DynamicColor dependency without deleting ColorPicker dependency.